# unable to show axis tick label in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a stacked bar chart with ggplot. Below is my code:

```
df = data.frame(Y = c(0,0,1,1), X = c(0,1,0,1), N = c(200, 50, 300, 70))

ggplot(data=df, aes(y=N, x= X, fill=Y)) + 
                geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width=0.7)+
                scale_x_discrete(name ="", breaks = c(0, 1), labels=c("No",'Yes')) +
                theme(legend.position="none")
```

I want to show `'No' and 'Yes'` as tick label on x axis. But nothing shows up.  Does anyone know why my tick labelz do not show up? I do not understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Your x-axis is currently a continuous axis. You need to force it to be considered a factor for scale_x_discrete to work. Putting `x= as.factor(X)` for aes would solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to insert `factor(X)` to make X discrete rather than continuous:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Y = c(0, 0, 1, 1), X = c(0, 1, 0, 1), N = c(200, 50, 300, 70))

ggplot(data = df, aes(y = N, x = factor(X), fill = Y)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("No", "Yes")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it may be to do the data transformation outside the `ggplot` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(Y = c(0,0,1,1), X = c(0,1,0,1), N = c(200, 50, 300, 70))
df %>% 
  mutate(X = if_else(X == 0, "No", "Yes")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=N, x= X, fill=Y)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width=0.7)+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]